# Let's get critical: Feb 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Islam Stack Exchange](http://islam.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What is the name of the decorative circle around verse numbers?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21547/what-is-the-name-of-the-decorative-circle-around-verse-numbers)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Who can be a mahram for hajj?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21604/who-can-be-a-mahram-for-hajj)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is Hijama(Cupping) related to black magic?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/20293/is-hijamacupping-related-to-black-magic)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [If I have urine on my clothes but do not know it?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/20283/if-i-have-urine-on-my-clothes-but-do-not-know-it)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Are Mecca and Becca the same places?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21465/are-mecca-and-becca-the-same-places)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Why are we being tested?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21358/why-are-we-being-tested)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Is porn (pornography) allowed in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21524/is-pornography-allowed-in-islam)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Celebration of Eid ul Adha for a vegan muslim](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/20309/celebration-of-eid-ul-adha-for-a-vegan-muslim)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Can a temple be built in place of a Masjid?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/20319/can-a-temple-be-built-in-place-of-a-masjid)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [How do I pay back the debt I owed to my deceased mother?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21380/how-do-i-payback-the-debt-i-owed-to-my-deceased-mother)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

Answer (score 2):

I think the statistics shown here are really showing a **major** fundamental problem with understanding how voting is supposed to work.  I see *a lot* of disagreement about whether a post is "Excellent" or "Needs Improvement." That really shouldn't happen. It should be pretty obvious upon clicking a link which of those it is. As an example [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21524/is-pornography-allowed-in-islam) has a net score of -2, which I believe is warranted. But there was still one person who rated that post "Excellent" as well as 3 who rated it "Satisfactory." Even worse, that question currently has a score of +5. I think it is very important that we start educating people on how to make proper voting decisions here if we ever want Islam.SE to ever graduate.

Comment: I think this also goes back to the same core problem: not having an adequate community who are both fairly educated about Islam as a topic *and* the expectations of this site.

Comment: Oh, yeah dear infatuated, I assume not having an adequate communities ... could be considered as a significant problem. Hopefully we see more constructive changes in the site.

Comment: Besides, I strongly agree with you (@Daniel) that  "the statistics shown here are really showing a major fundamental problem with understanding how voting is supposed to work". Of course there could be some permanently problems such as bias... Good luck